# In Node-RED - filter text file based on index location and output to a new text file

Tags: javascript, node-red

I am trying to filter a text file in Node-RED using a start and an end index.

This is what my function node looks like:

```
var input = msg.payload;
var startIndex = 10;
var endIndex = 20;

var selectedText = input.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
msg.payload = selectedText;
return msg
```

However, I am not seeing anything returned in the debug node and am unable to write the filtered text into a file in node.

Here is my flow:

[image: fow]

Any advice would be very appreciated.

Comment: Edit the question to include an example of what is in the file